# Making Menu For Colored Dots

Tags: python, menu

I'm trying to make a little menu in my game where the player gets the chance to pick the colored dots they would like to have in the game. So far whenever I run the program nothing shows up. I want to be able to click for dots once I choose an option. Can someone please take a look at [my code](https://codehs.com/sandbox/id/new-sandbox-program-QfMxts?collaborate=-NU7r6mTN_3F0jN4yhr3)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.